# inviting people to blog and editing roles

Tags: blog, sharing

Is it possible to edit roles in my blog in sharing section? I want contributor role WITH uploading capability. Goal is that people I invite to write my blog can add their own images, but no publishing rights. The administer will  review it before publishing.

Comment: Yes it is possible, search for plugins. For example Members plugin by Justin Tadlock.

Answer (score 1):

By the below code you can give contributor to upload image.

```
function rwc_allow_contributor_uploads() {
    $contributor = get_role('contributor');
    $contributor->add_cap('upload_files');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'rwc_allow_contributor_uploads');`
```

And admin will review the post and then publish it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are beautiful plugin for you, [Adminimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/) and [User role editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) where you can edit the user's role as per your choice.